# Selenium | Element not interactable error: Explored all the options of stack overflow

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get all drop downs from a web page and select a value from them in one go. 
I have attached a code snippet which gets all the dropdowns which are bootstrapped and under  tag on the web page.
I want to access children of each ul tag which are under li tag and click on any of those children.
I am attaching the screen shot taken from web site.
It always says element not interactable eventhough it is clikable element.
Please help.

[Application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E6d8.png)

**Code:**

```
List<WebElement> dropDowns = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'dropdown')]"));
try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch (Exception e){};
 for(WebElement webElement : dropDowns){
            try{
                List<WebElement> elementList = webElement.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'dropdown')]//li"));
                for (int i = 0 ; i < elementList.size();i++){
                    elementList.get(i).click();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("-----------Error----------");
                continue ;
            }
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(10000);}
            catch (Exception e){}
            webDriver.quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see below issues in your code.

- You are trying to use the `webElement` from `dropDowns` list which will through stale element exception if you use `webElement` in the for loop.
- Your code will perform the operation on the first operation on the first dropdwn all the times as you are not getting the downdown based on the index.
- you mentioned you want to select an item in the list but you are clicking on the each item in the dropdown.

Please try with the below logic.

```
int dropDowns = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'dropdown')]")).size();
try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch (Exception e){};
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
for(int dropdownIndex =0; dropdownIndex < dropDowns; dropdownIndex++){
            WebElement dropdown = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'dropdown')]")).get(dropdownIndex);
            try{
                List<WebElement> elementList = dropdown.findElements(By.xpath(".//li"));
                for (int i = 0 ; i < elementList.size();i++){ // not sure if you really want to click each item in the dropdown, hence not modified this part.
                    WebElement item = elementList.get(i);
                    js.executeScript("arugments[0].click()",item);
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("-----------Error----------");
                continue ;
            }
}
```